# Magento: data in collection is not complete?

Tags: magento, collections

I have created a collection ($myCollection) in Magento and I get its data using this code:

```
$data = $myCollection->getData();
```

That works, but when I look at the $data array, I see that some columns are just missing and the strange thing is, only sometimes, NOT always. To figure out whats going on, I fetched the underlying SQL using this code:

```
$select = $myCollection->getSelect()->__toString();
```

Running this in my MySQL client returns all columns, nothing is missing. Any idea what the problem might be?

Thanks!

Comment: enable mysql logging by turning on the $_debug variable to true. That makes magento log all queries. on top of that look for mysql table locks

Comment: I logged the queries, executed the one that fetches what I need and executed it in my SQL client ... everything looks fine. The data in the collection is still missing though. If there was a lock, wouldnt that mean that different column would be missing, not the same each time?

Answer (score 0):

this is correct, not always full data is included, especially for eav models. You can read about it on

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-8-varien-data-collections

to load all of them, additionally use:
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');